# Auto-resize images in Opera

Tags: opera, resizing, opera-10

Is there a setting that I can configure to automatically scale large images like Firefox does?

I'm using Opera 10.53, and when I open a large image in a new tab, it is not scaled at all.  I'm on a laptop, so it is hard to view, and when I am viewing multiple images, it is tedious to scale each image down to 20% or whatever fits it best.

I found [this thread](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=320531), and for a fleeting moment thought I had found the answer, but apparently not.  They just told the poster to manually resize.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Newest Opera versions (since 11.10) auto-resize automatically, clicking an image resizes it to original and clicking it again resizes it back to window port height. Lovely, you're gonna love it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this user script (Opera has the ability built in to run user scripts) http://userjs.org/scripts/browser/enhancements/autosizer  It should do the trick.